# variable colons for indexing in Python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have a Numpy array **A** that has a certain number of dimensions. For the rest of the question I will consider that **A** is a 4-dimensional array:

```
>>>A.shape 
(2,2,2,2)
```

Sometimes, I would like to access the elements

```
A[:,:,1,:]
```

, but also sometimes I would like to access the elements

```
A[:,1,:,:]
```

, and so on (the position of the '1' in the '1'-colon indexing "chain" is a variable).

How can I do that?

Comment: @Kanak Yup. Thanks. Do I delete the question?

Comment: No do not delete it. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a `:` when indexing, python calls that a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice).  When you provide comma-separated slices, it is really just a tuple of slices.

The `:` is equivalent to `slice(None)`, so you can get the same effect with the following

```
>>> my_index = (slice(None), 1, slice(None), slice(None))
>>> A[my_index] == A[:,1,:,:]
True
```

You can build up your indexing programatically with this knowledge.